# Best practice for two tinyint columns that cannot be both 0

Tags: mysql, tinyint

i have a question about the best practices about this situation:
I have a mysql table that contains (besides the other columns) two columns that are both TINYINT(1) but they can't be both on 0, they can be 0 and 1, 1 and 0, 1 and 1 but no 0 and 0.
What's the best way to control this? is even a way to control this?

Edit: i think i will choose the ENUM option but how this will perform if i combine mysql with Entity Framework?

Comment: That's a tough one. What are the columns for? Knowing how they'll actually be used may help people suggest solutions.

Comment: The columns are for a system delivery configuration, the values are is_physical_delivery and the other is is_digital_delivery so can be one, the other or both

Comment: Then I would probably agree with the answers suggesting an enum that contains the possible values, in a single column named like `delivery_configuration`. :)

Comment: For this case, I agree... something like this: `ALTER table ADD delivery ENUM('physical', 'digital', 'both') NOT NULL` would describe the data accurately.

Comment: Did you end up going with `SET` or `ENUM`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options I can think of:

- Validate in before update/insert triggers
- Validate in application logic
- Add a foreign key reference with acceptable states
- Use an ENUM with all the possible combinations, and don't allow NULL

I would probably use the last approach, personally.

**EDIT:**

Just realized--the `SET` data type accomplishes this perfectly.

Comment: SET is cool and fast, but in this case it would allow all kind of invalid values.

Comment: @landons Set('0','1') would not allow '1','1'. Set('01','10','11') would allow the combined value '01','10','11'. Which set do you mean?

Comment: I mean `SET('digital', 'physical') NOT NULL` would allow "digital," "physical" or "digital,physical"

Comment: @landons ah, that makes more sense then the original 0,1. So the honour is yours to ask the right question and give a much better answer then the original question was. But even in a not null SET you can store empty values without even a warning. I know an enum also stores simply an empty string when not in strict mode and fed with a wrong value, but that at least gives a warning.

Comment: @flaschenpost The original question didn't account for putting in a 2 ;).  This isn't a replacement for proper validation.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using an enum, combined from both values. They are stored quite efficiently. So it would be `enum('0;1','1;0','1;1') not null`.

EDIT:

Given the additional information, and following @landons suggestion, just for the record: the enum would be

```
delivery enum('physical', 'digital', 'both') not null;
```

You could use (also following @landon)

```
delivery SET('physical','digital');
```

But that would allow empty values.

Comment: You could use `NOT NULL` on the `SET` too ;)

Comment: And I really like how you've combined my main suggestions into your answer

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to combine your two columns into a BIT(2) column, then when you perform your update you could test that you weren't updating the column to b'00'.

As for a built-in prevention, I do not believe there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could achieve this by putting them together in 1 column.

- first number represents `1`
- second number represents `2`

Your column could then contain values `1`, `2` or `3`. When it is `0`, they both are.

With `2` and `3` the second number would be `1`. With `1` and `3` the first number would be `1`.